# How to define LyX to switch from Hebrew to English automatically when I pass to Math mode?

Tags: math-mode, lyx, languages

I am working in Hebrew in LyX and I want it to switch to English automatically when I pass to Math mode. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

This usually happens if you use your operating system keyboard layout for lyx instead of its own. See http://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/HebrewOnLinux:

> You can use LyX-keyboard mapping instead of Linux-keyboard mapping for Hebrew.
>   For some people, that is more continent, as you do not have to change
>   keyboard-layout when you switch into math-mode.
>
> 1. Editing->Keyboard/Mouse -- mark "Use keyboard map" and set the "First" to 'null' and the "Second" to 'hebrew'.
> 2. Editing->Shortcut -- Press on "New" button and in the "Function" field write 'language hebrew", and then set shortcut key as you desire. This key will toggle Hebrew\English.

The same instructions should work as well for Windows. After following them, you'll set the keyboard as English, and switch in LyX (it is a semi-convention to map `F12` as the keyboard shortcut in LyX to switch keyboards).